# как получить byte из image?

Tags: java, android

Вот камера мне возвращает Image я хочу его архивировать для этого мне нужно получить поток byte как это сделать?

Я работаю с Camera2API и вот метод из которого я получаю Image

```
@Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
       image = reader.acquireNextImage();
          }
```

Я эти image складываю в Map и потом мне необходимо сделать из них архив и этот архив отправить на сервер...

Если я все правильно понимаю то когда я создаю архив я открываю файл в который буду записывать байты моего изображения и складываю эти файлы в архив. Вот тут и вопрос как получить byte из image?

Answer (score 2):

Вот так это должно работать

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        FileOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
            output.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            mImage.close();
            if (null != output) {
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

С Camera2API не работал, но попробую предположить.
Хранить несколько снимков в памяти уже не есть хорошо, можно получить `ООМ`.
Сохраните все файлы во внутренней памяти телефона, а в памяти держите на них ссылки. Как только нужно будет положить в архив - воспользуйтесь этим кодом
[воспользуйтесь этим кодом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7485668/2667883)

Comment: Да но моя картинка  типа Image, а не Bitmap

Comment: Как вы получаете тип Image? на сколько я знаю в java нет такого класса, есть 2 варианта получения изображения через запуск нативной камеры, где вы предаете файл в интент, и камера его сохраняет на SD карте. Либо у вас переопределена камера, но в это случае вам как раз возвращается byte[]

Comment: Добавьте в ваш вопрос, как вы получаете Image? И Главный вопрос дня - зачем вы хотите архивировать изображение?

Comment: добавил код и описание

Comment: обновил ответ, надеюсь это окажется полезнее )

Comment: Кажется я нашел как это должно работать, но теперь появился еще вопрос. Моя идея была в том, чтоб не загружать память телефона картинками. Ок, если картинки будут храниться в телефоне, то можно их удалять вместе со созданным архивом сразу после отправки?

Comment: Почему бы и нет? =) Вы создаете, вы и удаляет =) Если вам они точно не нужны после отправки, смело удаляйте.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37057/discussion-between-aleksey-timoshchenko-and-chaynik).